# Linux kernel module compilation fails

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel

My last kernel development was in version 2.6~
Now I try to compile a module, and I get the following error when compiling outside the kernel tree.

```
/bin/sh: 1: /home/blabla/workspace/kernel35/linux-3.5/scripts/recordmcount: not found
```

The object file is created properly, however the problem is within the kernel Makefile itself, something has changed and I wasn't updated ?

I'm using vanilla kernel sources from kernel.org, and I already did

```
make oldconfig && make prepare
```

I posted the Makefile that I'm using, it's a standard makefile for kernel modules

```
# Comment/uncomment the following line to disable/enable debugging
#DEBUG = y


# Add your debugging flag (or not) to CFLAGS
ifeq ($(DEBUG),y)
  DEBFLAGS = -O -g -DBLABLA_DEBUG # "-O" is needed to expand inlines
else
  DEBFLAGS = -O2
endif

ccflags-y += $(DEBFLAGS)
ccflags-y += -I..

ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
# call from kernel build system

obj-m   := blabla.o

else
KERNELDIR ?= /home/blabla/workspace/kernel35/linux-3.5
PWD       := $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

endif

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c .tmp_versions

depend .depend dep:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -M *.c > .depend


ifeq (.depend,$(wildcard .depend))
include .depend
endif
```

Comment: Did you try `make KERNELDIR=<path to your kernel>`.  The file you have has a default of */home/blabla/../linux-3.5*.  Is that where your kernel source is?  Actually, it looks like `KERNELDIR` is a path to the build tree. Are build and source different?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, I figured out how to solve this.
apparently, this is the first time I'm trying to compile a module without compiling the kernel beforehand.
to solve the issue I run the following command from the kernel source tree.

```
make modules_prepare
```

this creates all the necessary infrastructure to support modules building.